# SQLAlchemy integrity error after trying to update row with new info that isn't primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am making a website where one can submit a coding prompt for other people to try. However, I want to add the ability to update submissions so that So far, my code is

```
function = form.function.data
func_call = function[function.index('def') + 4: function.index(':')]
func_name = func_call[:func_call.index("(")]

param = {
    "function": function,
    "testCaseInputs": form.testCaseInputs.data,
    "testCaseOutputs": form.testCaseOutputs.data,
}

try:
    Problem.query.filter_by(func_name = func_name).first().update(param)
    db.session.commit()

except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
    db.session.rollback()
    traceback.print_exc()

finally:
    db.session.remove()
```

When I try to commit it, I get the following error: sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: problem.func_name

But I'm not sure why given that I'm not even updating the primary key (which is func_name). My understanding of update(param) is that update will take my dictionary, and then update just those columns.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm not sure what more to add; this is a section of code that gets called upon submitting a form, in which the db.session.commit() is called.